# grep count search multiple words

Tags: bash, grep

how do I search for lines that contain multiple words? I want an "AND" relationship.
I want a total count of such lines.

```
grep -c -E "tok1.*tok2" file
```

return 0

Comment: Please provide an example of an input file.

Comment: so you want a count of lines that contain tok1 AND tok2?

Answer (score 4):

To use grep specifically, you can use the OR operator to allow for both possibilities:

```
grep -c -E "(.*tok1.*tok2.*|.*tok2.*tok1.*)" file
```

You can also simply grep for one token, and then pipe that to a recurring grep for another token:

```
grep "tok1" file | grep -c "tok2"
```

Multiple greps seem to be much faster when you start introducing a lot of tokens. You can also substitute for the **egrep** command, which is a regexp version of grep...but I avoid it for the same reason: it seems to me to take drastically longer when you introduce multiple terms into the search.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to grep, there is awk:

```
awk '/tok1/ && /tok2/ {count++} END {print count}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

egrep "tok1" file | egrep -c "tok2"